# Centering the element horizontally inside the element without using specific values

Tags: css

Again, just learning CSS and trying to make a fictive homepage.
Here's a problem I came by:
I want to **center the links and their background colors** inside a DIV- element. However, I also want to keep the DIV centered (**15% from each side**) and changing the text inside the links will still center them, so the **positioning can't be a specific value** (need to use per centages, I think).

**EDIT:** Long explanation shortly: I want to get all four blocks in the middle of the page regardless of changing the size of the browser screen or the texts inside the blocks. Thanks :)

**EDIT2:** Changed the title to be found more easily from the Search- query.

Anything can be done to the code or do I have to change it somehow? Thanks.
Here's the HTML:

```css
.infos {
padding-left: 15%;
padding-right: 15%;
position: relative;
top: 40px;
}

.infos a {
background-color: black;
color: white;
margin: 0px;
display: inline;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
text-decoration: none !important;
}

.infos #centered {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<DIV CLASS="infos">
  <DIV ID="centered">
 <A HREF="#" ID="membership">Application for Membership</A>
 <A HREF="#" ID="rules">Rules</A>
 <A HREF="#" ID="terms">Travel Conditions</A>
 <A HREF="#" ID="meetings">Meetings</A>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#centered {
display:table;
background:red;
margin:auto;
}
#centered a {
color: white;
margin: 0;
float:left;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<DIV ID="centered">
 <A HREF="#" ID="membership">Application for Membership</A>
 <A HREF="#" ID="rules">Rules</A>
 <A HREF="#" ID="terms">Travel Conditions</A>
 <A HREF="#" ID="meetings">Meetings</A>
  </DIV>
```